# Finding specific keyword from website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

hello I want to extract specific keywords from website listed in CSV file, and then list the number word word available in specific website but my code is not working, Could you guys please help me

I have an excel sheet with name dai.csv and test.CSV, dai.csv contains wesites link in row

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import bs4 as bs
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests

with open("dai.csv", "r") as scoreFile:
    scoreFileReader =csv.reader(scoreFile)
    scoreList = []
    for row in scoreFileReader:
       if len (row) != 0:
            scoreList = scoreList + [row]

scoreFile.close()


req = Request('scoreList', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(webpage,'lxml')
url = ("techyardnepal.com")

text = soup.get_text()
#word =  input("Enter the word")
word1 = input("input word")
count1 = (text.count(word1))
#word =  ("is")
print(count1)
print(url)

with open("test.csv", "r") as scoreFile:
    scoreFileReader =csv.reader(scoreFile)
    scoreList = []
    for row in scoreFileReader:
        if len (row) != 0:
            scoreList = scoreList + [row]

scoreFile.close()


with open ("test.csv","a") as scoreFile:
    scoreFileWriter =csv.writer(scoreFile)
    scoreFileWriter.writerow([url,word,count1])

scoreFile.close()
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: It would help if you [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47135922/edit) to include samples from your CSV files to make it possible to recreate. Also show what output you are hoping to get for some given input.